# Need formula to add enough zeros to total 10 characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to tweak the below formula, so that instead of always adding 5 zeros, it adds enough zeros to equal 10 values (characters).  I'm using this in a system (iCIMS), and the result (depending on the status of specific people, i.e., A1 and A2 in this mock) needs to be first initial, last initial, system id, with enough zeros to equal 10 values.

```
Example: Kiki James  System id: 123  Result: KJ12300000
Example: Bob Jones System id: 2345   Result: BJ23450000
```

The below was working for a while; however, now the system id's have grown to 4 digits (so some folks have 3 digits and some 4).

```
IF(OR(A1="yes",A2="yes),Left(B1)&Left(B2)&B3&"00000","")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REPT` does what you need. It appends enough `0` until there are 8 characters. Add that to the 2 initials, and the total length is 10.

```
=IF(OR(A1="yes",A2="yes"),LEFT(B1)&LEFT(B2)&B3&REPT("0",8-LEN(B3)),"")
```

[image: sample data]

Napoleon Solo's System id is too long.